# Unwanted CiviRule email sent to Admin

Tags: civirules

I have a client with a simple set-up. When A assigns an activity to B with C, then B and C get notified per e-mail with a special template. But also D (me i.e Admin) and I'm not mentioned in any of the civirule and this address doesn't either show up in any parameter for e-mails.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no strange behaviour, just lack of information ;-) A trainee was using this e-mail address to create 'Activity'

Comment: Thanks for sharing!

Comment: I feel a bit awkward :-/

Comment: There is no need for that :-)

Answer (score 0):

It will be configured somewhere, CiviRules does not automatically send unspecified email in my experience:-) Is there something else, a Scheduled Reminder or a configuration somewhere?

Comment: I've checked and found no scheduled reminder. I'm often using CiviRules and I can't figure out why I face this strange behavior :-(

Comment: Neither can I from a distance, all I can say is that it is highly unlikely that it is caused by CiviRules? We would have had remarks all over the place if it did.....

Comment: I know, this is a very strange behaviour. I'll need to investigate deeper.